# Obtaining the Width in Pixels of any given character

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, graphics, fonts

I have this really awesome idea, but cannot find out if there are any classes in the .NET Framework (any version, preferrably 3.5 or 4.0) that allow you to pass in a character, and get back the width in pixels of that character, no matter which font, or font size or font-decoration is being used. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Does a class/something even exist for something like this?

Comment: Oh, boy! It seems as though I am now confronted with a dilemma. Two perfect answers. One for Windows Forms and another for WPF. But only 1 answer can be accepted. Hmm, what to do...

Comment: When in doubt accept the answer that is the oldest, which is @Paul's

Comment: Thanks @Broken. Accepted. And sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) method.

Code sample adapted from the link:

```
SizeF charSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString("X", new Font("Arial", 16));
// do stuff with charSize ...
```

The sample above assumes you're in the function body of a Paint event handler and the Graphics object is already created for you and passed in as an event parameter. If you don't want or can't do it in a Paint handler you can create a graphics object at your convenience with [Control.CreateGraphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much @Paul, and thanks for taking the time to include a sample! I think I remember hearing about `MeasureString(String, Font);` once before now that you mention it.

Comment: `MesureString` returns its measurement in `PageUnits` which is a value of `GraphicsUnits` which is an enumeration; only one of the enums is `pixels`. So be careful, this might not always be in pixels. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

If WPF works for you (I see someone just removed the WPF tag for this question, but it was there originally) there is also [`FormattedText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.aspx):

```
FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText("hello foo",
                                                CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
                                                FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                                                new Typeface("Arial"),
                                                FontSize = 14,
                                                Brushes.Black);
double width = formattedText.Width;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code sample, @BrokenGlass! This is *also* what I was looking for!

Comment: +1 Nice WPF-based solution. Are there any performance consideration when using this method of getting the width? I ask because performance can be an issue if Control.CreateGraphics is not used and disposed properly. Wondering if there's any such gotchas with FormattedText?