# How can I apply half star Grid RowDefinition Height?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to define a row with half star (*) height.

I've tried Height="*/2" but is wrong... Obviously.

Can somebody tell me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590083/obtaining-the-width-in-pixels-of-any-given-character

Comment: You would need to multiply any other rows measured in stars by 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
<RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
```